# How to determine if a mobile user visiting your site is on their cellular network vs. connected to WiFi

Tags: php, html, http, web

We built a site that obtains your location (when connected to wifi, getting the local router) and shows you things in your area. But if you are on your cellular network, it is going to display the wrong things because the cellular network router could be hundreds/thousands of miles away.

Is there a way to determine if a user is on their cellular network by http request? The only thing we have come up with so far is to build a list of the most common cellular network routers around the U.S. and void those areas completely - not very efficient. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's really no practical way to do it unless you want to hope the reverse DNS is correct

Comment: WiFi (and wired) routers can also be *way* far away from the user's actual location (either in fact, or because the GeoIP database is incorrect). In my experience cheap GeoIP providers are about 85% accurate, and the most expensive ones don't get above 95%.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to check latency somehow, and may see a big difference for cellular networks when you test it.

That said, the most reliable way would be to ask the user directly, and let them put in where they really are if the detected location isn't accurate.  It would be also useful to do that in general, to see things in another area that someone is planning to go to in the future.

Comment: I'll pass this along, thanks. But it does look like we're just going to have to ask the user's location permission for mobile devices